# see cloud functions logs in detail

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to delete elements from 2 different collections in firestore using a cloud function. I am doing:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { GoogleAuth } = require("googleapis-common");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const firebase_tools = require("firebase-tools");
const firestore = admin.initializeApp().firestore();
const Buffer =  require('buffer');
const PROJECT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT;
const PROJECT_NAME = `projects/${PROJECT_ID}`;

exports.removeFromShoppingList = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async(snap, context) => {
  const db = firestore;
  const batch = db.batch;
  const shoppingCartId = snap.shoppingCartId;
  const shoppingListId = snap.shoppingListId;
  const productId = snap.productId;

  try {
    
    if (!(context.auth && context.auth.token)) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'permission-denied',
        'Must be an administrative user to initiate delete.'
      );
    }
    const pathShoppingListDetailsCollection = db.collection('shoppingListDetails').doc(shoppingListId)
      .collection('products').doc(productId);

    batch.delete(pathShoppingListDetailsCollection);

    const pathShoppingListsCollection = db.collection('shoppingLists').doc(shoppingCartId)
      .collection('shoppingListCart').doc(shoppingListId).collection('products').doc(productId);

    batch.delete(pathShoppingListsCollection);
    await batch.commit();

  } catch(err){
    functionCalledToHandleError();
  }
})
```

And in the client in flutter I call the cloud function like this:

```
Future<void> removeProductsFromShoppingList({
required String shoppingCartId,
required String shoppingListId,
required String productId
}) async {
try {
  final data = {
    'shoppingCartId': shoppingCartId,
    'shoppingListId' : shoppingListId,
    'productId' : productId
  };

  var delete = functions.httpsCallable('removeFromShoppingList')
      .call(data);

} on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (err){
  print('estamos en el FirebaseFunctionsException ');
} catch (e) {
  throw CouldNotDeleteNoteException();
}
```

}

And I am getting an error when I do the `batch.delete(pathShoppingListDetailsCollection)` when I go check the logs in the google cloud console the only message that is helping is the  textPayload that says `textPayload: "There was an error deleting the documents"` is there a way to see this logs more in detail. Because with only this information I don't know the reason why I cannot delete the documents.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your complete code including the imports so we can see where all the variables like batch are coming from ?

Comment: If you log `err`, does it show any more details about why the batch delete failed?

Comment: I edited the original post and added the new code. But the problem is not just about fixing this code issue now, but about being able to get more information from the logs in the future in order to know exactly what the actual problem is. For example, in this case what I would like to know from the logs is why exactly I can't delete the document instead of just saying that there is a problem while deleting. I would like a more precise explanation like "It couldn't be deleted because the path is wrong". I don't know if I'm explaining myself correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Frank van Puffelen said with the log err I got some more information about the error and I could solve the problem, thank you so much.

In my case the error was that `batch.delete` was not a function and that was because I missed parentheses when declaring the `const batch = db.batch()`